# How to zip project and use it as a resource in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I've got the following project structure

- /server (Spring Boot)
- /import/src/main/resources

  - xls
  - img

I would like to zip all files inside `/import/src/main/resources` and put it inside the spring boot as a resource named "import.zip".

The `import` project is just a simple `base` plugin project.

I would like to zip this `import` directory every time I build the server.

How to organize `build.gradle` files? I don't want to create additional, custom tasks. Basically, I want to invoke `gradle clean build` and have my fatjar with import.zip ready to go.